# what is all these templates when creating new ASP.NET web application in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, visual-studio-2019

Excuse my question and my English 
I have started learning ASP.NET, The problem is i followed a lot of tutorials,
But in all of them they always choose another template or the same in some videos

I just want to know 
    - What is the difference 
    - Would it effect the process in developing the website 
    - And would it effect the result or not
    - And which one should i choose for a site like this http://old.brackeys.com/

Photo of the templates
https://serving.photos.photobox.com/797009418a5ba2bc54de0a6ad89bd076943d8f05e2138321a38657dc45bc46c19e84571b.jpg

Comment: Yes they would change the result and process relatively significantly. They have different purposes. If they didn't, there wouldn't be much point in having different templates. You can read about each one online already if you google the titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those templates are just **boilerplate** code for a web application, like a foundation upon which you can build your own web application.

The template you chose depends mainly on your skill set, for example if you are good with `angular` you may choose the `angular` with `.net` template.

The website you have referenced can be build with any of the web application templates.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio templates in general are different sample or predefined working projects that provides a framework or direction of a project.

What mainly differ among the templates is the technology or design pattern you will be employing when you select one. However, you may achieve the same project goal using any template of your choice. You may look here for more details https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet